# Listen to Mic through Speakers on a Dell Chromebook

Tags: speakers, microphone, chromebook, input, audio-output

I'm aware that in Windows 7 you can play the **microphone input out of the computer speakers**.

I have a Dell Chromebook and am wondering if this is possible on **Chrome OS**.

I checked the Settings areas and cannot find an appropriate option. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **it is not currently possible** to play the Microphone input out of the speakers of a Dell Chromebook. There is no functionality within Chrome OS to allow such use of the inbuilt Microphone.

For reference, it is possible to play the Microphone input out of the computer's speakers in Windows 7 and later editions by:

- Right-clicking the Speaker icon (in the Windows 7 Notification Area) and selecting the "Recording Devices" option
- Selecting the "Listen" tab and checking the "Listen to this device" box.

The levels and sensitivity of this output on Windows can be adjusted accordingly if necessary.